# detail view cant find pk

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Fairly new to Django and Python, I am trying to build a detail view and a list view for a bunch of pictures I have uploaded. My list view works and shows all the pictures I have but I cannot figure out how to create a detailview that would let me look at only one picture.

In my "mysite" directory I have a url.py containing

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^photo/', include('photo.urls', namespace = "photo")),
)
```

Then in my "photo" directory I have

from photo import views

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'$', views.ListImage.as_view(),name ='Photo-List',),
    url(r'^/image/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ImageView.as_view(),name='image-view',),

)
```

I have uploaded a bunch of pictures and I can see them when I visit my local website 800local../photo. But if I want to see one picture only, the address ../photo/image/1 returns a 404.

My Folder can be found at https://github.com/henrigeek/Django

Comment: Are you using same index.html for both list view and detail view?

Comment: I used code you provided which works. Are you sure you are using the right url file? You said that the list view works, can you post your urls.py file for both list view and detail view please.

Comment: url(r'$', Listviews.View.as_view(),name='photo-list',),

Comment: Sorry it's views.ListView.as_view()

Comment: I think your list view url blocks everything, if you change it to `r'^list/$'` or put your detail view url before the listview url, it should work.

Comment: I added ^ and blocked List with a "#" but my display wont work? If I use pk =1 it should show me a picture right? I have created a few pics with the admin website and my "photo/add" webpage. But photo/display/1 does not work

Comment: urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #url(r'^$', views.ListImage.as_view(),name ='Photo-List',),
    url(r'^image/add$', views.ImageCreate.as_view(), name = 'create-image',),
    url(r'^display/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.ImageView.as_view(),name='image-view',),
    url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.ImageUpdate.as_view(),name='image-update',),

Comment: Hey, it's hard to help you with small piece of your code at a time, I created a sample project base on your code, have a look there https://github.com/tianyi33/django-exmaple

Comment: @tmaster https://github.com/henrigeek/Django - this is my project (photo) the only difference with what you do is that I have 2 urls.py -> one in my mysite using include and the other in the photo folders. I do not understand what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List view will return object_list and Detail view return object.

```
{% if object %}
{{object.title}}
................
{% else %}
{% for img_obj in object_list %}
{{ img_obj.title }}
................
{% empty %}
No images found
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

You can refer here [Class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)

Comment: Hi Geo, thanks for the tips but I think the issue right now is that I cant even access my template. I think the <pk> is not recognized. For instance, when I try to access http://localhost:8000/photo/image/1/ (pk=1), the page returns 404 No image found matching the query

Comment: Any Help? I am quite desperate. Can someone explain to me why my page won't show